# Absorption of light in a medium with non-uniform optical density

Tags: absorption

[image]I want to understand how exactly is the optical absorption signal obtained in the case of a medium with non-uniform optical density (OD). Do all volume elements along the direction of light propagation have the same contribution in the absorption of light that will be obtained at the photodetector?

Lets for simplicity first take the case of light propagating in a homogeneous medium. I assume a small jar filled with Rb vapor that can be characterized by homogenous optical density (OD) and hence corresponding to uniform attenuation constant. At the bottom of the jar at coordinate $z = 0$ a source of light field is situated. The light propagates thought the medium and is detected by a detector positioned at coordinate $z = l$. Here I assume that the light is monochromatic and with a frequency chosen such that resonance absorption occurs. In the above-mentioned uniform case the intensity of transmitted light along the height of the jar is shown with the green dashed curve and is given by: $I_{\textrm t}(z) = I_0 e^{-\alpha z}$, where $I_0$ is the light intensity of the source (incident at  $z = 0$) and $\alpha$ is the attenuation constant.  Therefore the intensity of the detected signal is: $I_{\textrm {detected}}(z = l) = I_0 e^{-\alpha l}$.

Since I would like to investigate the case of non-uniform OD and hence non-uniform attenuation constant along the path of light propagation a simple step distribution of the OD is assumed - in the figure the attenuation in the first half distance is described with $\alpha_1$ while for the second half $\alpha_2$ is assumed, where $\alpha_1 = 2\alpha_2$. 
In this case the signal originating from position $z = 0$ has intensity $I_0$ and before arriving at the detector will be attenuated by a factor of $e^{-\alpha_1(z_1 - z_0)}e^{-\alpha_2(l - z_1)}$. The signal originating from the middle: $z_1$ has intensity $I_0e^{-\alpha_1(z_1 - z_0)}$ and it will be further attenuated traveling to the detector by $e^{-\alpha_2(l - z_1)}$. So due to the attenuation, it seems to me that regardless the distance from the source all volume elements have equal contribution to the absorption signal observed at the detector even in the case where the attenuation is non-uniform - is this a valid consideration?

Answer (score 1):

For the case of uniform absorption coefficient you correctly stated that

$I_{\textrm {detected}}(z = L) = I_0 e^{-\alpha L}$

From here it is quite easy to go for the general case where $\alpha = \alpha(l)$:

$I_{\textrm {detected}}(z = L) = I_0 \int _{l=0}^{l=L} e^{-\alpha(l) l} dl$

From there it is just solving the integral for a the given $\alpha(l)$

Comment: I understand the general integrated case, but I am not sure for the local differential contribution. Somehow, from the case of uniform OD  I had the intuition that most of the signal comes from the vicinity of the source (the beginning of the optical path. It seems to me now that all volume elements have equal weight in the absorption.

Comment: @AntonI Yes you are right, every differential length element dl reduces the previously transmitted part by the same weight (if $\alpha$ is constant). However, due to the exponential nature of the absorption the absolute amount of absorbed light is decreasing when l gets bigger. So for nearly transparent media, every volume element does in fact contributes approximately the same. For high absorbing materials however, you are correct, most of the light is absorbed shortly after the entrance into the absorbing material.